# Intuit CAD API with PHP

Tags: php, sdk, intuit-partner-platform

Been trying to figure this out all week. Intuit doesn't officially have a PHP sdk, but they [link](https://github.com/treehousetim/phpaggcat) to one that hasn't been touched in 2 years.

I have followed all the steps here:
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/007_firstrequest

And that all works fine. I can use the API Explorer to begin pulling information.

My question is how do I use this outside the Explorer?

Not sure how to use the .p12 file and when I use the [linked](https://github.com/treehousetim/phpaggcat) SDK, I continually get Error 400 Code:MissingRequiredField,Type:SYSTEM.

Quite lost on which direction I need to go to tackle this. New to SAML.

Please help me find the best way to use this API with PHP.

Thanks

Comment: Post your code and configuration that goes along with it

Comment: @identigral The code is here: https://github.com/treehousetim/phpaggcat/blob/master/example.php and my config file looks like this: http://paste.ofcode.org/Vic7JLrNqq6U7CdkDK2LPE

Comment: At a quick glance it appears that you're using the PHP library correctly but the devil is always in the details. I would try getting in touch with the guy who wrote this PHP wrapper.